# Change background of Metro TextBox at normal state

Tags: xaml, textbox, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a C#/XAML Metro-style application with a TextBox. By default, the TextBox displays with a gray background. When I hover over it with my mouse, the background lightens. When I put my focus into the TextBox, it has a white background.

I want to create a XAML style that will cause the TextBox to always have a white background, regardless of the position of my mouse or where my focus is in the application - how can I do this?

Thanks!

Andrew

Comment: Open project with Blend. Right click on textbox and "create template with copy" or somthing similar. Blend should generate a copy of the default template that you can edit.

Comment: You can do the same thing in Visual Studio 11 design view too now.

Comment: It's Right Click/Edit Template/Edit Current

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the control template.